# UITableViewCell subviews not showing

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

[image: Picture 1]

My table has a cell with one immediate descendant inner view, which is bound to all sides of the content view.

Inside the view there is a multiline label, bound to all sides of that view. There's another test view that I am using to see if any descendant views show up.

Here's how it looks in interface builder:

[image]

Here's all the constrains:

[image]

However, when I run it, none of the inner subviews are visible.

Basically it looks like this (only the container is visible):

[image]

Here's my cellForRow method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageSlideshowTableCell") as! ImageSlideshowTableCell
        } else  {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DescriptionTableCell") as! DescriptionTableCell
        } 

        return cell
    }
```

And here's the DescriptionTableCell:

```
class DescriptionTableCell:UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleText: UILabel!
}
```

I cannot figure out what is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is going on in cellForRow method?

Comment: post your cellForRow method!

Comment: Posted, not sure how useful it is though, I'd say it's probably a constraint problem?

Comment: Your view is in front of your label, is it what you want ?

Comment: That's the little magenta box on the right, for testing purposes it doesn't matter. I just want any of the subviews showing up

Comment: But your label is hidden behind the purple view no, and also can you see your cyan view box in front of the purple one? And did you try to set a text to your label inside your DescriptionTableCell ?

Comment: But the label is the child of the purple view.. How can it be hidden? I tried printing the label's text inside my controller and it showed up in the console

Comment: See if the titleText is nil. Could you set a value to cell.titleText in cellForRowAtIndexPath and log it after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Label is inside a View, not inside your cell. However, that doesn't matter because the label is the child of the view.

I tried to reproduce the issue with a slight difference and it is working fine.

[image]

and when I run it, I got-

[image]

The difference is, I didn't add the extra hidden view, you are talking about. so, check if that is blocking the label.

Comment: Hm.. Even if I delete that small magenta view my output is still not showing the label.. My problem must be somewhere else then.. I will try re-making the view and report back

Comment: Wow, works fine.. Must be a silly checkbox I checked somewhere that I shouldn't have.. Thank you!